# How to implement "copy to clipboard" in browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to implement "copy to clipboard" in JavaScript? Is there any way to add JS scripts in HTML that allows a "copy to clipboard" button"?
The example in the image below.
When you press a copy button, the command is copied to clipboard

[image: copy command from hub.docker.com]

Example from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with Markdown.

Comment: Ho to do this in HTML? What is the name of this element in HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this neither in plain Markdown nor in plain HTML. This feature is provided by static site generators (for example, [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io)) and it uses JavaScript under the hood. Check [this super simple tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) for more help on how this works.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? When clicking on the button the text in the `textarea` is selected with [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) and copied to the clipboard with `navigator.clipboard.writeText`

```js
function copyCode(el) {
  let copyText = el.nextElementSibling;
  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
  //console.log(copyText.value);
  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value)
    .then(() => {
      alert("successfully copied");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```

```css
.copyButton {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

textarea {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: dimGray;
  color: white;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.material-icons {
  color: lightGray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<pre style="width:100%;background-color:dimGray;color:white">
<button class="copyButton" onclick="copyCode(this);"><i class="material-icons">content_copy</i></button>
<textarea type="text" style="">
// ES5
var x = function(x, y) {
   return x * y;
}

// ES6
const x = (x, y) => x * y;
</textarea>
</pre>
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/jewauft9